# Drupal 6 Feeds Module User Import & Ubercart

Tags: 6, users, ubercart, feeds, importing-exporting

I've noticed that in Drupal 7 there is a way to map fields for importing users, but I don't see the same option for Drupal 6. Am I missing something? I'm trying to import users that include address fields from a CSV, but I can't see a way to map it all correctly.

I need to import addresses, phone numbers, zip codes, join dates, etc. and make sure they're mapped to the correct member/user fields in Drupal/Ubercart

Answer (score 0):

After searching high and low I finally found a workable solution.

Using [user_import module](http://drupal.org/project/user_import) in conjunction with this [little custom module here](http://drupal.org/node/709726#comment-3577720) I was able to import all of customer information from the old site.

It was exactly what I was wanting to do. All I had to do was match up the fields to my CSV file and I was able to get it all added in ot the appropriate uc_addresses tables.